# Grants.gov v NIH ASSIST for grant submission

Tags: funding, united-states, nih

I am writing a training grant--what is the difference between Grants.gov and NIH ASSIST for submission? Is one preferable to another?

Comment: There are similar issues with submitting NSF grants through grants.gov rather than NSF's Fastlane system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionally, you can use whichever system you prefer; there is no inherent advantage in submitting via either system, since both are approved methods for submitting proposals.

The decision on which system to use basically boils down to which system you feel is easier, and which one your university's grants and contracts administrators are more comfortable using. (The easier it is for them to use the system, the easier it will be for you to submit your proposals according to the rules and deadlines!)

Comment: One practical issue with using grants.gov is that will do its computerized checking of the proposal before sending it on to NIH and then NIH will do a second round of checking.  If NIH finds something wrong with the application, then you'll have to update on grants.gov and resubmit.  This can be slow down the process of submitting your proposal and might cause a huge problem if you miss the deadline.